# Ambari Error installing App Timeline Server

Tags: hadoop, ambari

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/hooks/before-ANY/scripts/hook.py", line 35, in <module>
BeforeAnyHook().execute()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 280, in execute
method(env)
File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/hooks/before-ANY/scripts/hook.py", line 32, in hook
setup_java()
File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/hooks/before-ANY/scripts/shared_initialization.py", line 212, in setup_java
Execute(install_cmd,
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/base.py", line 155, in __init__
self.env.run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 160, in run
self.run_action(resource, action)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 124, in run_action
provider_action()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/providers/system.py", line 273, in action_run
tries=self.resource.tries, try_sleep=self.resource.try_sleep)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 70, in inner
result = function(command, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 92, in checked_call
tries=tries, try_sleep=try_sleep)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 140, in _call_wrapper
result = _call(command, **kwargs_copy)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 293, in _call
raise ExecutionFailed(err_msg, code, out, err)
resource_management.core.exceptions.ExecutionFailed: Execution of 'cd /var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/jdk_tmp_Sb7Zbx && tar -xf /var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/jdk-8u77-linux-x64.tar.gz && ambari-sudo.sh cp -rp /var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/jdk_tmp_Sb7Zbx/* /usr/jdk64' returned 2. gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
Error: Error: Unable to run the custom hook script ['/usr/bin/python', '/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/hooks/before-ANY/scripts/hook.py', 'ANY', '/var/lib/ambari-agent/data/command-3845.json', '/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/hooks/before-ANY', '/var/lib/ambari-agent/data/structured-out-3845.json', 'INFO', '/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp']
```

This error occurs in the process of installing App Timeline Server, in one of the
ambari agents.Does anyone has the save problem ever?

Comment: Try installing `jdk-8u77` on your own to that machine. Also HDP 2.0.6 is really old. Have you tried upgrading ever?

Comment: I found the problem, the file gotten from the namenode went wrong. When i delete the file in that machine works.